# Using Getter and Setter for arraylist in java

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to set and get an `ArrayList` from setter and getter methods of android. But I am new to android and Java and don't know how to do that? Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

List<String> list = null;

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    List<String> sample = new ArrayList<String>();
    sample.add("element 1");
    test.setList(sample);
    List<String> sample1 = test.getList();
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For better Encapsulation / OO design I would do following

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestListGetterSetter {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

//Return copy of the list
public List<String> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(list);
}

// Copy source list into destination list
public void setList(List<String> listToBeSet) {
    if (listToBeSet != null)
        this.list.addAll(listToBeSet);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListGetterSetter testListGetterSetter = new TestListGetterSetter();

    List<String> clientList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "HiHa"));

    testListGetterSetter.setList(clientList);
    System.out.println("TestListGetterSetter.list before clientList modification = " + testListGetterSetter.getList());

    //Now you can change "clientList" without affecting testListGetterSetter object
    clientList.add("1");
    System.out.println("clientList modified List = " + clientList);
    System.out.println("TestListGetterSetter.list after clientList modification = " + testListGetterSetter.getList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this does not sound right in all cases, because sometimes the user of this api may want to get the list using `getList()` and add some elements to it. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

```
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();  

    public ArrayList<String> getArrList() {
        return arrList;
    }

    public void setArrList(ArrayList<String> arrList) {
        this.arrList = arrList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally getter and setter methods are for assign variable and get variables value from that

```
There is not any difference of getter and setter methods for arraylist or for int of a class 

ArrayList<String> arrList;

    public ArrayList<String> getArrList() {
        return arrList;
    }

    public void setArrList(ArrayList<String> arrList) {
        this.arrList = arrList;
    }
```

**Same for Int**

```
int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with android. 
But in JAVA, if you want to use set and get method, you need to declare the List first.

```
private List arrayList = new ArrayList();

public List getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}

public void setArrayList(List arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
```

Comment: I haven't see this kind of declaration....private List arrayList = new arrayList;

Comment: Still missing buddy checkout my answer how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
  public static ArrayList<books> al = new ArrayList<books>();
  books book=new books(id,name,type);
                book1 b1=new book1(id,name,type);
                al.add(book);
                al.add(book1);   //error at book1
```

Comment: book1 is same class using same pakage  .

Comment: I want to acces both with one one array list object

Answer (score -1):

Try these

```
public ArrayList getArrayList() {
    return arraylist;
}

public void setArrayList(ArrayList arraylist) {
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
}
```

Comment: your setter definitely doesn't do what it's intended to, right?

Comment: @LalitPoptani Buddy it is understood that he has a member variable. Why would you be writing a getter/setter for otherwise.

Comment: @RahulChoudhary OMG, public void setArrayList(ArrayList arraylist) {
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
}
 is this the way you set and arrayList? instead of changing your answer you are bouncing back on me.